# HP PDX Laptop and blu-ray region on HP MediaSmart 

Tags: blu-ray, regional-settings, hp-mediasmart

I have a laptop here, a [HP HDX 16 EO1000](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?product=3826112) with a Blu-Ray drive.

Installed on the machine is a software package called HP MediaSmart, which presumably can play Blu-Ray movies.

However, when inserting a BD disk and starting HP MediaSmart, it comes up with a warning screen and the following message:

> This disc has been coded for Region B only and will not play in this machine. Please eject this disc and play on a Region B player.

The question is, can we change this region? The machine is in europe, which is the B-region, but apparently the drive, or software, or both, is set to some other region. I don't even know where to find the current setting so if anyone knows, please post an answer with some information of where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After downloading and installing a trial of Cyberlink PowerDVD, and using its settings menu to change the region code, MediaSmart was able to play the movie.